# Error related to ngrok

Tags: linux, apache, http, ngrok

I have recently installed ngrok version 1.6 on my ubuntu. While running command
`ngrok http 80`

I am getting a following error.

`You may only specify one port to tunnel to on the command line, got 2: [http 80]`

Please tell me the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ngrok 1.6 there was no extra param (http) to pass, the correct invocation for ngrok 1.6 would be `ngrok 80`. However, I'd suggest upgrading, ngrok 1.6 is fairly old (I'm running 2.1.3 for example).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a relative path, such as.

```
./ngrok http 80
```

instead of

```
ngrok http 80
```

But for me it shows this:

```
./ngrok: file or directory doesn't exist
```

Comment: I also got "./ngrok: file or directory doesn't exist" error. But then I have tried the command from home directory and it worked !!

Answer (score 3):

If you are Facing this following error:-

```
You may only specify one port to tunnel to on the command line, got 2: [http 80]
```

**Than you need to Use this:-** `./ngrok http 80` **instead of** `ngrok http 80`

Answer (score 0):

You need to download zip file from https://ngrok.com/download
Unzip it, You'll get a file called ngrok, goto that directory in command line and run `./ngrok http 80`